# If case in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I  have an excel input and it has two filed AB and AB1. Here AB1 contains null value(or blank). My aim is to check that if AB1 is null or blank then result will contains AB. That is:

```
if AB1 is null or blank then
  AB
else
  AB1
```

I tried with formula option in pentaho like this

```
=IF([AB1]=NULL();[AB];[AB1])
```

How can I address this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you at least post a screenshot of your Excel input? It would help us to help you.

Comment: I just added screen shot on my question..